# What does inflate mean in women inflate?

Tags: meaning

"he’s likely never made eye contact with a woman he didn’t have to inflate."

Some people says this about me. What does it mean?

Comment: Not a flattering comment. "It is likely that he has only been intimate with inflatable sex dolls, not real women", or possibly "he is too shy or cowardly to make contact with real women and has to make do with sex dolls".

Comment: I got it. Okay that's what it means

Comment: Please just turn that into an answer LOL

Comment: .....bloatware.

Comment: I think we're being trolled, folks.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a flattering comment. "it is likely that he has only been intimate with inflatable sex dolls, not real women", or possibly "he is too shy or cowardly to make contact with real women and has to make do with sex dolls".

Comment: Patch kits included.